# Does client need to persist and refresh token itself when using Azure Active Directory Library?

Tags: android, xamarin, active-directory, xamarin.android, adal

In our Xamarin.Android app, we are using ADAL for .Net v3.13.5 to get the access token.

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(AD_AUTHORITY);

if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Count() > 0)
{
    authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);
}

var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(API_RESOURCE_ID_URI, CLIENT_ID, new Uri(REDIRECT_URI), new PlatformParameters(callerActivity));
return authResult.AccessToken;
```

It seems the token is stored by ADAL only in memory. Every time the app restarts, the user has to login again.

Is there a way to make ADAL persist the token, so that the token is available even if app restarts, or the app itself needs to take care of token persistence and refresh logic?

Comment: On Android, they automatically save the tokens into `SharedPreferences` via an Base64 string so assuming you are not uninstalling and reinstalling the app, the access/refresh token will be cached in between app runs..

Comment: @SushiHangover Not uninstalling/reinstalling. In between the app runs (User leave the app, app gets destroyed by android, User again open the app) itself the user is presented again with Login screen.

Comment: Is `authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Count()` equal to zero? Is the code in your question within the `Xamarin.Android` project? In a PCL library? If this code is not within the `Xamarin.Android`, have you added the ADAL nuget to your main project? https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/blob/c5c66c097a6499e0c646f5ed1db1d6d278683104/src/ADAL.PCL/AuthenticationContext.cs#L134

Comment: @SushiHangover yes, authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Count() is equal to zero. 
Also, yes, the code in my question is within the app, xamarin.android project.  ADAL (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory) nuget is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is a bug serialization that results in the issue you are seeing. This means you would have to take ownership of the TokenCache yourself when constructing the AuthorizationContext.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/58736/crash-in-release-build-when-using-datacontractjsonserializer

Comment: Thanks. Serilization bug was causing the issue. On using <AndroidLinkSkip>System.Runtime.Serialization</AndroidLinkSkip> as workaround, things are working fine now :).